# Django - include a child template cannot find template

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to include a page into another one like this

```
<div id="past_comments">
    {% include 'comment_block.html' %}
</div>
```

and the structure of my directory is like:

|-post

|----comment_block.html

|----detail.html

|----index.html

[screenshot of structure in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsTDl.png)

However, I get an exception:

*Exception Type:    TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:

comment_block.html*

Can any body help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: edit you post replace image to text

Comment: @BearBrown I have changed it

Comment: replace 'comment_block.html' with 'post/comment_block.html'

Comment: @mohammedqudah Yeah, it works! Thank you! I don't know it needs start from the parent directory

Comment: please mark my answer as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tell django that your template dir is in post
then you include the *comment_block* so django will lock in

`post/templates/comment_block.html`

but your file is not there its in

`post/template/post/comment_block.html`

so you need to include your file like this `{% include 'post/comment_block.html'%}`